# How can i add html elements on alertify.JS prompt dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alertify

I need to add more input elements on alertify dialog box.
What is the best way of doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

i did add extra inputs into text

```
var text = '<input id="extra-field" />';
```

and then by jQuery get values

```
alertify.confirm(text, function(e){
   if(e){
       var extra = $('#extra-field').val();
       ...
   });
```

for me isn't a problem, but the compoments are not in the same layout. Anyway i hope it will helps to you. Have a nice day.